# I'm not able to copy an Input Field value to multiple fields using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have been working on this system for a while now, and I've run into a small problem.

What I want to do: Copy all the data entered in an input field with id 'totalentered' into all the input fields with id 'totalclasses'

What is happening instead: There are multiple fields with the id 'totalclasses', generated using a while loop in PHP. However, the data is ***only being copied to the first input*** field with id 'totalclasses', rest of them remaining unchanged.

I'm just not able to figure out what's wrong. 
Here's my HTML+PHP code

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Total Classes Taken" id="totalentered">
<!--PHP Code, deleted because it would make reading this post too tiresome-->
<tr>
<th scope="row"><?=$row['rollnumber']?></th>
<td><?=$row['name']?></td>
<td><?php echo $selectedmonth; ?></td>
<td><input data-parsley-type="digits" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Classes Attended" name="attended<?= $cnt; ?>" id="attended"></td>
<td><input data-parsley-type="digits" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Total Classes Taken" id="totalclasses" name="totalclasses<?= $cnt; ?>"></td>
<input type="hidden" name="student_id<?= $cnt; ?>" value="<?=$student_id?>">
<input type="hidden" name="testmarks<?= $cnt; ?>" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="assignmentmarks<?= $cnt; ?>" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true">
```

Here's my JavaScript code which should be doing the job:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('form').parsley();
        });
        $(function() {                                       // <== Doc Ready
            $("#totalentered").change(function() {           // When the total number of classes are changed
                $('#totalclasses').val(this.value);          // copy it over to the individual student for convenience
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Anyone who can help me out with what's wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: _There are multiple fields with the id 'totalclasses'_ - [The `id` attribute must be unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454645/does-id-have-to-be-unique-in-the-whole-page), so you will need to change this.

Comment: Any idea what alterations I can make, to get the desired result? I need it to be replicated into all those fields which are being generated...

Comment: Use class instead ...  Id will work only for first element

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention, it was working when I originally wrote this code for multiple fields with the same ID, for some unknown reason.

Comment: @AshishKumar the class is same even for fields which aren't supposed to have that data, for styling purposes - that's the reason I didn't use class

Comment: you can give any no of class for an element   so build some logic to add unique classes for all record which has to be same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also agree that you should not use more than one id with the same name in your HTML. The great thing about jquery though is that you can use a number of ways to lookup an element. For instance:

```
<input myInput="great">Some text</a>
<script>
$( "input[myInput|='great']" ).val(this.value); //Search for an attribute name value pair
$( "input[myInput]" ).val(this.value); //Just search for an attribute name
$( "input[myInput*='eat']" ).val(this.value ); //star based search
</script>
```

You can see a full list of all available css selectors here:

https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Thanks - this was perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You should not have multiple elements with the same id. In your PHP code, change the `totalclasses` into a `class` attribute.

Then replace

`$('#totalclasses').val(this.value);`

with

`$('.totalclasses').val(this.value);`

From the [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/):

> Each id value must be used only once within a document. **If more than one element has been assigned the same ID, queries that use that ID will only select the first matched element in the DOM.** This behavior should not be relied on, however; a document with more than one element using the same ID is invalid.

Comment: Class is same even for fields which aren't supposed to have that data, for styling purposes - that's the reason I didn't use class...

Answer (score 0):

Write id in input field as id="totalclasses"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('form').parsley();
    });
    $(function() {                                       
        $("#totalentered").change(function() { 
            var cnt = "<?php echo $cnt ?>";
            $('#totalclasses' + cnt).val(this.value);         
        });
    });
</script>
```